# How do i change accent?

Tags: python, pyttsx

How do i change the accent in pyttsx3?

I've successfuly tried to change the voice and the rate at which it delivers the speech.

```
import pyttsx3
engine=pyttsx3.init()
voice=engine.getProperty('voices')[0]
engine.setProperty('voice',voice.id)
engine.setProperty('rate',100)
engine.say("Hello there!")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Change in the accent.

Answer (score 2):

To change the accent of the voice, you can use the `pyttsx3.setProperty('voice', 'en-us')` code.

It does not do much ...

But here is the complete code anyway

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')


engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty('voice', 'en-us')

engine.say("Hello World!")
engine.runAndWait()
engine.stop()
```

**or**

as mentioned in the other answer you can use a for loop to loop through all the different accents ...

As shown in the code below

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

for voice in voices:
    print(voice, voice.id)
    engine.setProperty('voice', voice.id)
    engine.say("Hello World!")
    engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
for voice in voices:
print(voice, voice.id)
engine.setProperty('voice', voice.id)
engine.say("Hello World!")
engine.runAndWait()
engine.stop()
```

Comment: So are you trying to say that different voices have different accents?

Comment: It does nothing.There is just  a change in the voice but not in accent.